# PHPUnit gives "Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()"

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I'm using Windows 7.

I've used PHPUnit fine on this system in the past.

On starting a new project, I'm getting the error above on my first attempt to run a test.

I've cleared cache on pear, totally uninstalled and "--force --alldeps" reinstalled PHPUnit and all dependencies - including PHP_CodeCoverage.

Short of rewriting pear from scratch - anyone got any ideas how I can fix this?

[edit] Below is the output of the "pear config-show" and "pear info phpunit/PHPUnit" commands

```
C:\Users\Jim\Documents\code\seleniumtests\phpunit\common>pear config-show
CONFIGURATION (CHANNEL PEAR.PHP.NET):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          C:\php5\pear\docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext
PEAR directory                 php_dir          C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          C:\php5\pear\cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         C:\php5\pear\data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php.exe
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         C:\php5\pear\tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          C:\php5\pear\www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            0
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Git\bin\gpg.EXE
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear.ini\pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear.ini\pear.ini
System Configuration File      Filename         C:\Program Files
                                                (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear.ini\pearsys.ini

C:\Users\Jim\Documents\code\seleniumtests\phpunit\common>pear info phpunit/PHPUnit
ABOUT PEAR.PHPUNIT.DE/PHPUNIT-3.6.10
====================================
Release Type          PEAR-style PHP-based Package
Name                  PHPUnit
Channel               pear.phpunit.de
Summary               The PHP Unit Testing framework.
Description           The PHP Unit Testing framework.
Maintainers           Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de> (lead)
Release Date          2012-01-27 10:49:19
Release Version       3.6.10 (stable)
API Version           3.6.0 (stable)
License               BSD License
Release Notes         http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/README.markdown
Required Dependencies PHP version 5.2.7
                      PEAR installer version 1.9.4 or newer
                      Package pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator
                        Version 1.3.0 or newer
                      Package pear.phpunit.de/Text_Template
                        Version 1.1.1 or newer
                      Package pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage
                        Version 1.1.0 or newer
                      Package pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer
                        Version 1.0.1 or newer
                      Package pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject
                        Version 1.1.0 or newer
                      Package pear.symfony-project.com/YAML
                        Version 1.0.2 or newer
                      Extension dom
                      Extension pcre
                      Extension reflection
                      Extension spl
Optional Dependencies Package pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Invoker
                        Version 1.1.0 or newer
                      Extension json
                      Extension simplexml
                      Extension tokenizer
package.xml version   2.0
Last Modified         2012-03-17 16:52
Previous Installed    - None -
Version
```

Comment: Delete `/usr/bin/phpunit` and reinstall. Make sure it gets created anew and doesn't mention `PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter` at all.

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately, Windows doesn't have /usr/bin at all. I've uninstalled and reinstalled already - twice.

Comment: D'oh! I missed the first line about Windows 7. My guess is that you have an old installation on the system or user PATH. You need to find the `phpunit.bat` that gets run when you type `phpunit` on the command line and delete it.

Comment: What do the following commands show? `pear config-show` and `pear info phpunit/PHPUnit`

Comment: Thanks David - I've added the output of those commands to the question - does that give you any clues? I can't see any mention of selenium in there at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I visited http://pear.phpunit.de/ and downloaded the latest PHP_CodeCoverage and PHPUnit_Selenium tar.gz files, uncompressed them, and copied all the files inside into matching folder locations within my PHPUnit install directory.

That seems to have done the trick!

Comment: Which was your PHPUnit install dir? Having the same problem and can't find the correct directory to do the same.